# Error with ES6 Imports with Jest and Parcel

Tags: jestjs, es6-modules, parceljs

I have a project using `react-parcel-app` as a template, and I'm trying to integrate Jest but I'm having the following error.

```
   Details:

/home/papaponmx/Projects/prime/src/actions/goals.spec.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { addGoal } from './goals.mjs';
```

This is what my `.babelrc` looks like.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {"modules": false},
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 2 versions"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "env": {
    "testing": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1", "react" ],
      "plugins": [
        "lodash",
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
        "dynamic-import-node"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that parcel is supposed to support ES Modules without configuration, but I don't get the test import s to work.

Here is the [link to the repo](https://github.com/papaponmx/prime/pull/12) in case you want to run it locally.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, i ended up going back to `require`

Answer (score 2):

By the help of [this article](https://ryankubik.com/blog/parcel-and-jest#remedying-the-lack-of-babel-situation) i come to a solution using babel.

1. Install these packages as dev dependencies:

   `npm i --save-dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env`
2. In the root level of your project, create a `.babelrc` file and add the following:

   `{presets:["@babel/preset-env"]}`

Then you can use ES6 imports in your test files

Comment: Not working for me :(